# Create platform game without creating a single game object per floor tile

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking forward to creating a 2D platformer. However, I felt it was bad practice to have a game object for every single tile and reading around proved that to be true. 
I then elected to use tile, draw my level and import it into unity. 
However, I came cross this tool "Ferr2D Terain" that makes everything easy.
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11653

However, while looking at it my question still remains. How does one even using this tool create 50 separate platforms, without having 50 separate gameObjects.

Regards

Comment: I would recommend first doing the tutorial "[2D UFO Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-ufo-tutorial)" This will teach you the basics of 2D in unity including how to place down objects in a efficent way.

Comment: I strongly disagree with what you wrote, having a gameobject for every tile is not bad at all. how else would it be possible? you might want to learn object pooling first and then try to optimize your game by minimizing the number of active objects in the scene. btw, empty gameobjects do not have any effect on performance.

Comment: @Bijan Well one method I know is drawing the tiles in Tiled and import it using Tiled2Unity. That way I have one "object" for all my platforms. 

So you're saying if I have a stage with 500 platforms and I have an individual game object for each platform. Aside from the obvious mess in the hierarchy...there's no performance impact?

Comment: well it's a general question, but there are many ways to reduce the impact, like making them static, or combining meshes, etc.